# How can people perform some Earth Release jutsu without having Earth Release as their chakra nature?

Tags: naruto

As I remember during Fourth Shinobi war, when Ten-Tails attack the shinobi with Biju-dama, 
Shikamaru had some idea to block it with some weak Earth Release that create wall (I don't remember the name of this technique).

So he asked Ino to connect him with some Iwagakure shinobi, (also forgot his name) to teach all of them to use the technique.
After the shinobi teaches them how to perform the technique, all the shinobi use this technique to block the Ten-Tail's Biju-dama.

**But how were shinobi who never seemed to have Earth Release able to perform this technique?** 
Just like Ino, Shikamaru, and Choji, who I've never seen use Earth Release technique before, were able to perform this Earth Release technique.

Comment: in the naruto universe, ninja can generally use any element. Their charka nature influences *how well* they can use an element.

Comment: if so, what is the purpose of that special paper that used to know our nature type?

Comment: i'm assuming its so the person can focus on the nature that most suits them. For example, if your interest in math and history are the same, but you suck at one, why would spend more time on that subject than you need to?

Comment: Remember Kakashi? He can use water(suiton),electricity(ranton),earth(doton),fire(katon) he doesnt have affinity but he can use them. The only person with afinnity for all elements should be the Rikudou, that controls chakra in all its forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How can people perform some Earth Release without having Earth Release as their chakra nature?**

Because  Earth Chakra Affinity is not the requirement to do the earth release technique but it gives you edge if you have the respective Affinity.

So if paper test prove you to be have Affinity to Wind Release that doesn't means you can't do non wind released Jutsu.

From [naruto.wikia.com](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_transformation#Affinity)

> Shinobi have an easier time learning to create and control chakra
>   natures that match their affinity, although even then it may take any
>   number of years. Shinobi are not limited to the nature they have an
>   affinity for, and it is in fact common for jōnin to have mastered two
>   natures. Although it is technically possible to master all five
>   natures, it is very rare because of how much of training is involved;
>   Madara Uchiha, Hiruzen Sarutobi Hashirama Senju, Tobirama Senju,
>   Mū, Kakashi Hatake, and Orochimaru are the only shinobi known to have
>   done so via normal means.

Answer (score 0):

Higher level character can use more than two element, like first, second, third hokage (Because they are the hokages). Uchiha clan people like Madara, Itachi, Sasuke and also Kakashi sensei can use all element because of the copying technique of the sharingan. Other people can also use more than two element but not as good as their own nature element.

For example: using chakra to control or manipulate element is also ninjutsu same like shadow clone jutsu. Sasuke can create max of 3 clone but Naruto can do multi clone jutsu.

In a battle its a matter of life and death.so ninja try to use the weapon that they are trained and mastered with..so only they use only two nature element in which they are strong in.